# PHP | MAC | Netbeans IDE | xDebug on Remote Server & DropBox

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, xdebug, dropbox

If the above keywords are all familiar to you, then you can probably guess what I'm trying to do.

The question is if it is possible to do xDebugging a PHP page residing on a remote ( goDaddy ) server, using MAC a version of NetBeans where the local copy of the PHP file is kept in dropbox.

So that...

When you goto another MAC (that has the same setup), you can open up the dropbox and check out the most up-to-date php file that you worked on knowing that it must be synced to the remote server. ( here, I won't be editing the dropbox file, I'd be just viewing - cause I  will exclusively be working on the remote server directly and here netbeans would be saving a local copy for only backup purposes, therefore there is no point for me to work on the local ( dropbox ) copy. )

If this set-up is not logical, you may suggest similar but alternative set-ups. I think the dropbox component here is the one that complicates things. But I'm not sure if the idea is good to even begin with. Some discussion would prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be possible - but seems somehow senseless to me. You should go and setup a VCS like Subversion or - preferably - git, to achive a central code management.